# How to make Horizontal Progress Bar Thin and Change the Internal Progress Color

Tags: android, layout

I want to Make Horizontal Progress bar Thin i want to change Internal Progress Color Change when Progress is Increase.

```
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar1" 
android:layout_width="100dip" 
android:layout_marginTop="200dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
android:indeterminateOnly="false"
android:progressDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_horizontal"
android:indeterminateDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal"

/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](http://huuah.com/android-progress-bar-and-thread-updating/) will help you to create progress bar that can be updated by thread.

You can use this style to create small progress bar

```
<style name="Widget.ProgressBar.Small">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_small_white</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxWidth">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">16dip</item>
</style>
```

And you can use following code to change color.

```
ProgressBar pg = (ProgressBar)row.findViewById(R.id.progress);
final float[] roundedCorners = new float[] { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
pgDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(roundedCorners, null,null));
String MyColor = "#FF00FF";
pgDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor(MyColor));
ClipDrawable progress = new ClipDrawable(pgDrawable, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
pg.setProgressDrawable(progress);   
pg.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.progress_horizontal));
pg.setProgress(45);
```

Hope this can help !!

Comment: Use this style . its looking charm for me.  style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse"